# RestKit to Core Data mapping and loading zero objects. RKManagedObjectLoader

Tags: iphone, ios, rest, core-data, restkit

I have been struggling with getting my project using RestKit to save my JSON objects into Core Data.  I have RestKit 0.10.2 and have gone through a hodgepodge of tutorials and cobbled together something here.  I had previously reached success when my Event was an NSObject, and I did not implement Core Data.  Now that I am using Core Data for persistence, I am having issues getting the JSON into the database.  Everything I've tried either calls the objecLoader with [0] objects, or as it is now, I can't get the objectLoader to get called.

My Xcode console output after showing the JSON shows this message:

```
2012-12-11 19:44:43.508 fish[19404:15b03] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:34 Creating thread-local entity cache for managed object context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x11249470>
2012-12-11 19:44:43.508 fish[19404:15b03] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:50 Caching instances of Entity 'Event' by primary key attribute 'eventId'
```

And hangs at this point:

```
    libobjc.A.dylib`property_getAttributes:
0x1cecd27:  pushl  %ebp
0x1cecd28:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1cecd2a:  movl   8(%ebp), %eax
0x1cecd2d:  movl   4(%eax), %eax
0x1cecd30:  popl   %ebp
0x1cecd31:  ret
```

rootViewController.h

```
    @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, RKObjectLoaderDelegate> {

    NSArray *eventsArray;

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton;

    User *user;
    RKClient *client;
    RKObjectManager *objectManager;
    NSArray *data;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *eventsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *data;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;     

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *addButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *user;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RKClient *client;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RKObjectManager *objectManager;

rootViewcontroller.m

    @implementation RootViewController


@synthesize eventsArray, managedObjectContext, addButton, locationManager;
@synthesize objectManager;
@synthesize user, client, data;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle
- (User *)user {
    if (user == nil) {
        //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ObjectiveResourceConfig getSite]];
        self.user = [User currentUserForSite:gBaseURL];
        [user addObserver:self];
    }
    return user;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    LocationsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (LocationsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    [self configureRestKit];
    client = appDelegate.client;

    // Initialize RestKit
    RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:gBaseURL];
    objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:gBaseURL];
    objectManager.client.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;
    objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;
    objectManager.client.username = self.user.login;
    objectManager.client.password = self.user.password;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = appDelegate.managedObjectModel;

    NSString *databaseName = @"Fishn.sqlite";
    //RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore =[[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] init];
    objectManager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:databaseName usingSeedDatabaseName:nil managedObjectModel:managedObjectModel delegate:self];
    objectManager.objectStore = managedObjectStore;

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Enable automatic network activity indicator management
    objectManager.client.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;

    //NSLog(@"===> %@ / %@",objectManager.client.username,objectManager.client.password);
    objectManager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"Fishn.sqlite"];

    [self setupMapping];

    [self sendRequest];
}

    - (void)configureRestKit {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    gBaseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:3000"];
#else
    gBaseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:3000"];
#endif
    //self.user.login = @"user@example.com";
    //self.user.password = @"please";

}

- (void)sendRequest
{

    [objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/events.json" delegate:self];
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKManagedObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {
    if ([request isGET]) {
        if ([response isOK]) {
            NSLog(@"Data returned: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
        }
    } else if ([request isPOST]) {
        if ([response isJSON]) {
            NSLog(@"POST returned a JSON response");
        }
    } else if ([request isDELETE]) {
        if ([response isNotFound]) {
            NSLog(@"Resource '%@' not exists", [request resourcePath]);
        }
    }
}


- (void)objectLoader:(RKManagedObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
    NSLog(@"Number of objects [%d]", [objects count]);
    data = objects;
    self.eventsArray = objects;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)setupMapping {
    RKObjectMappingProvider *omp = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider;
    RKManagedObjectMapping *eventMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Event class] inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
    [eventMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"id",@"eventId",
     @"name",@"name",
     @"amount",@"amount",
     @"length",@"length",
     @"updated_at",@"updatedAt",
     @"created_at",@"createdAt",
     @"latitude",@"latitude",
     @"longitude",@"longitude",
     @"thumbnail",@"thumbnail",
     @"airTemp",@"airTemp", nil];
    eventMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"eventId";
    eventMapping.rootKeyPath = @"event";

    [omp addObjectMapping:eventMapping];
    [omp setObjectMapping:eventMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/events.json"];
    //[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/events.json" delegate:self];


    //[eventMapping mapAttributes:@"name", @"amount", @"latitude", @"longitude", @"airTemp", @"length",@"thumbnail", nil];
    //[eventMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
    // @"created_at", @"createdAt",
    // @"updated_at", @"updatedAt",
    // @"id", @"eventId",
    // nil];
}

Event.h

    @class Photo;

@interface Event : NSManagedObject  {

    NSNumber *eventId;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *amount;
    NSDate   *updatedAt;
    NSDate   *createdAt;
    NSNumber    *latitude;
    NSNumber    *longitude;
    NSNumber    *airTemp;
    NSNumber    *length;
    UIImage *thumbnail;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *thumbnail;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *creationDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Photo *photo;


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *eventId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *amount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *updatedAt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *createdAt;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *airTemp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *length;

@end
```

Here is my console log:

```
    2012-12-12 21:46:03.144 fish[30797:11f03] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit initialized...
2012-12-12 21:46:03.256 fish[30797:11f03] AppDelegeate I am your RKClient singleton : <RKClient: 0x9838ee0>
2012-12-12 21:46:03.257 fish[30797:11f03] Uname and PW = user@example.com , please
2012-12-12 21:46:03.264 fish[30797:11f03] User has street cred
2012-12-12 21:46:03.265 fish[30797:11f03] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2012-12-12 21:46:03.266 fish[30797:11f03] I restkit.support:RKCache.m:189 Invalidating cache at path: /Users/yoshi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/6BB57AD9-7949-4B0B-A1B5-4441005FA87A/Library/Caches/RKClientRequestCache-localhost/SessionStore
2012-12-12 21:46:03.267 fish[30797:11f03] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:162 Reachability observer initialized with hostname localhost
2012-12-12 21:46:03.268 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network:RKClient.m:294 Reachability observer changed for client <RKClient: 0x79542b0>, suspending queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x79543f0 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=0 loadingCount=0/5> until reachability to host 'localhost' can be determined
2012-12-12 21:46:03.268 fish[30797:11f03] I restkit.support:RKCache.m:189 Invalidating cache at path: /Users/yoshi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/6BB57AD9-7949-4B0B-A1B5-4441005FA87A/Library/Caches/RKClientRequestCache-localhost/SessionStore
2012-12-12 21:46:03.294 fish[30797:11f03] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:391 Network availability has been determined for reachability observer <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x983d860 host=localhost isReachabilityDetermined=YES isMonitoringLocalWiFi=NO reachabilityFlags=-R -----ld>
2012-12-12 21:46:03.294 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network:RKClient.m:437 Reachability to host 'localhost' determined for client <RKClient: 0x9838ee0>, unsuspending queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x9839300 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=0 loadingCount=0/5>
2012-12-12 21:46:03.295 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network.queue:RKRequestQueue.m:338 Queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x9839300 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=0 loadingCount=0/5> has been unsuspended
2012-12-12 21:46:03.295 fish[30797:11f03] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:391 Network availability has been determined for reachability observer <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x983c6c0 host=localhost isReachabilityDetermined=YES isMonitoringLocalWiFi=NO reachabilityFlags=-R -----ld>
2012-12-12 21:46:03.296 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network:RKClient.m:437 Reachability to host 'localhost' determined for client <RKClient: 0x79542b0>, unsuspending queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x79543f0 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=1 loadingCount=0/5>
2012-12-12 21:46:03.296 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network.queue:RKRequestQueue.m:338 Queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x79543f0 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=1 loadingCount=0/5> has been unsuspended
2012-12-12 21:46:03.297 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network.queue:RKRequestQueue.m:309 Sent request <RKManagedObjectLoader: 0x7c5c860> from queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x79543f0 name=(null) suspended=NO requestCount=1 loadingCount=1/5>. Loading count = 1 of 5
2012-12-12 21:46:03.299 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:437 Sending asynchronous GET request to URL http://localhost:3000/events.json.
2012-12-12 21:46:03.301 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:198 Proceeding with request to <NSURLRequest http://localhost:3000/events.json>
2012-12-12 21:46:03.315 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:175 Asked if canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: with authenticationMethod = NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault
2012-12-12 21:46:03.315 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:147 Received authentication challenge
2012-12-12 21:46:03.418 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:219 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 304
2012-12-12 21:46:03.419 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:220 Headers: {
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
    Connection = close;
    Date = "Thu, 13 Dec 2012 02:46:03 GMT";
    Etag = "\"1a8ebe93a30136774e4a26d6f0d3b714\"";
    Server = "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-02-16)";
    "X-Request-Id" = 404311fe98d4bf07e27c13171346a593;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.097077";
    "X-Ua-Compatible" = "IE=Edge";
}
2012-12-12 21:46:03.420 fish[30797:11f03] I restkit.network:RKRequest.m:680 Updating cache date for request <RKManagedObjectLoader: 0x7c5c860> to 2012-12-13 02:46:03 +0000
2012-12-12 21:46:03.421 fish[30797:11f03] Data returned: [{"event":{"airTemp":72.1,"amount":1,"created_at":"2012-11-25T01:21:29Z","id":1,"latitude":55.5555,"length":22.0,"longitude":-88.88888,"name":"Grouper","thumbnail":null,"updated_at":"2012-11-25T01:21:29Z","user_id":1}},{"event":{"airTemp":69.1,"amount":2,"created_at":"2012-11-27T16:30:51Z","id":2,"latitude":33.333,"length":36.0,"longitude":124.4555555,"name":"Haddock","thumbnail":null,"updated_at":"2012-11-27T16:30:51Z","user_id":null}}]
2012-12-12 21:46:03.421 fish[30797:11f03] D restkit.network.queue:RKRequestQueue.m:501 Received response for request <RKManagedObjectLoader: 0x7c5c860>, removing from queue. (Now loading 1 of 5)
2012-12-12 21:46:03.422 fish[30797:16707] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:280 Beginning object mapping activities within GCD queue labeled: org.restkit.ObjectMapping
2012-12-12 21:46:03.422 fish[30797:16707] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:267 No object mapping provider, using mapping provider from parent object manager to perform KVC mapping
2012-12-12 21:46:03.423 fish[30797:16707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:336 Performing object mapping sourceObject: (
        {
        event =         {
            airTemp = "72.09999999999999";
            amount = 1;
            "created_at" = "2012-11-25T01:21:29Z";
            id = 1;
            latitude = "55.5555";
            length = 22;
            longitude = "-88.88888";
            name = Grouper;
            thumbnail = "<null>";
            "updated_at" = "2012-11-25T01:21:29Z";
            "user_id" = 1;
        };
    },
        {
        event =         {
            airTemp = "69.09999999999999";
            amount = 2;
            "created_at" = "2012-11-27T16:30:51Z";
            id = 2;
            latitude = "33.333";
            length = 36;
            longitude = "124.4555555";
            name = Haddock;
            thumbnail = "<null>";
            "updated_at" = "2012-11-27T16:30:51Z";
            "user_id" = "<null>";
        };
    }
)
 and targetObject: (null)
2012-12-12 21:46:03.423 fish[30797:16707] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:275 Found mappable collection at keyPath 'event': (
        {
        airTemp = "72.09999999999999";
        amount = 1;
        "created_at" = "2012-11-25T01:21:29Z";
        id = 1;
        latitude = "55.5555";
        length = 22;
        longitude = "-88.88888";
        name = Grouper;
        thumbnail = "<null>";
        "updated_at" = "2012-11-25T01:21:29Z";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
        {
        airTemp = "69.09999999999999";
        amount = 2;
        "created_at" = "2012-11-27T16:30:51Z";
        id = 2;
        latitude = "33.333";
        length = 36;
        longitude = "124.4555555";
        name = Haddock;
        thumbnail = "<null>";
        "updated_at" = "2012-11-27T16:30:51Z";
        "user_id" = "<null>";
    }
)
2012-12-12 21:46:03.424 fish[30797:16707] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:34 Creating thread-local entity cache for managed object context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x795c1a0>
2012-12-12 21:46:03.424 fish[30797:16707] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:50 Caching instances of Entity 'Event' by primary key attribute 'eventId'
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your server JSON response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapping this question since I moved to RestKit 0.20pre4 and it is different than 0.10.2